# How can I configure the triggers of my DevOps pipelines to trigger on change within the power platform solution

Tags: azure-pipelines, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I got an issue with my DevOps pipes for my power platform solutions. I want them to trigger only if there are changes within the source (the power platform solution).

In the triggers tab within DevOps Pipelines I checked the "only schedule builds if the source or pipeline has changed", but still the pipelines triggers all the time on the selected dates.

[image: scheduled trigger]

Do you know how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance